# Sessions In PHP not working

Tags: php, session

okay so I am getting users to sign in and then "if successful" I redirect them to index.php where I would like to display some info from the database.

my users are validated and I can log in but I think I having issues with the Session.

The user name session does not display any info when I call it on the index.php page.

I am new to php and learning as I go. I have spent the last two days browsing this site for answers to my issue, but can't find anything that really works.

Here is the code

checklogin.php

```
<?php

    session_start();
    ob_start();
    include_once 'config.php';

    // Connect to server and select databse.
    try
    {
        $pdo_options[PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE] = PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION;
        $db = new PDO('mysql:host='.$host.';dbname='.$db_name.';charset=utf8', $username, $password);
    }
    catch(Exception $e)
    {
        die('Error : ' . $e->getMessage());
    }   

    // Define $myusername and $mypassword 
    $myusername = $_POST['myusername']; 
    $mypassword = $_POST['mypassword']; 

    // To protect MySQL injection
    $myusername = stripslashes($myusername);
    $mypassword = stripslashes($mypassword);

    $stmt = $db->query("SELECT * FROM $tbl_name WHERE username='$myusername' and password='$mypassword'");

    // rowCount() is counting table row
    $count = $stmt->rowCount();

    // If result matched $myusername and $mypassword, table row must be 1 row
    if($count == 1){

        // Register $myusername, $mypassword and print "true"
        echo "true";
        $_SESSION['username'] = 'myusername';
        $_SESSION['password'] = 'mypassword';

    }
    else {
        //return the error message
        echo "<div class=\"alert alert-danger alert-dismissable\"><button type=\"button\" class=\"close\" data-dismiss=\"alert\" aria-hidden=\"true\">&times;</button>Wrong Username or Password</div>";
    }

    ob_end_flush();
?>
```

index.php

```
<?php
  session_start();

  if(!isset($_SESSION['username'])){
    header("location:main_login.php");
  }
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Login</title>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<!-- Bootstrap -->
<link href="css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" media="screen">
<link href="css/main.css" rel="stylesheet" media="screen">
</head>
<body>
<div class="container">
  <div class="form-signin">
    <div class="alert alert-success">You have been <strong>successfully</strong> logged in <?php echo $_SESSION['username']; ?>.</div>
    <a href="logout.php" class="btn btn-default btn-lg btn-block">Logout</a> </div>
</div>
<!-- /container -->
</body>
</html>
```

I would really appreciate any help or links to articles that can help.

Thanks

Sean

Comment: is your session is enabled? check by using phpinfo();

Comment: hi, here is what my phpinfo() has to say - http://prntscr.com/e2n4bn

Comment: so yes, I would say it is enabled

Comment: you have to write session_start(); on every page. Is it echoing "true"???

Comment: I have added this to every page and yes it is echoing true

Comment: In if($count == 1) condition what is the value of  $_SESSION['username'] ? did you echo?

Comment: In if($count == 1) condition after $_SESSION['password'] = 'mypassword'; add header redirect to index.php i.e.  header("location:index.php");

Comment: I am sorry what do you mean the value? It looks for username in db?

Comment: value means contents of session username. echo $_SESSION['username'] and check what it contains

Comment: It just logs me in successfully on the checklogin.php page

Comment: I added this to my index.php page 'echo $_SESSION['username']' it does not seem to return anything

Comment: i would recommend you to go through PHP tutorial on Youtube

Comment: okay thanks for trying @Mangesh

Comment: Just an update if it helps. The session is getting stored here - $_SESSION['username'] = 'myusername';

But it only returns the word myusername and not the actual client username

Comment: Ok. Now try comment ob_end_flush(); and in if($count == 1) add header location code to index.php

Comment: Okay it still only returns the word myusername

Comment: Got it! just change  $_SESSION['username'] = 'myusername'; to  $_SESSION['username'] = $myusername;

Comment: You sir are a legend!!!!

Comment: how do I mark this as the answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just change $_SESSION['username'] = 'myusername'; to $_SESSION['username'] = $myusername;